# How to allow clients to hook into preconfigured hooks in application

Tags: events, version-control, backend, webhooks, continuous-deployment

I have a pretty standard application with a frontend, a backend and some options in the frontend for modifying data. My backend fires events when data is modified (eg. record created, record updated, user logged in, etc.).

Now what I want to do is for my customers to be able to code their own functions and "hook" them into these events.

So far the approaches I have thought of are:

1. Allowing users in the frontend to write some code in a codeeditor like codemirror, but this whole storing code and executing it with some eval() seems kind of risky and unstable.
2. My second approach is illustrated below (to the best of my ability at least). The point is that the CRUD API calls a different "hook" web service that has these (recordUpdated, recordCreated, userLoggedIn,...) hook methods exposed. Then the client library needs to extend some predefined interfaces for the different hooks I expose. This still seems doable, but my issue is I can't figure out how my customers would deploy their library into the running "hook" service.

So it's kind of like webhooks, except I already know the exact hooks to be created which I figured could allow for an easier setup than customers having to create their own web services from scratch, but instead just create a library that is then deployed into an existing API (or something like that...). Preferably the infrastructure details should be hidden from the customers so they can focus solely on making business logic inside their custom hooks.

It's kind of hard to explain, but hopefully someone will get and can tell me if I'm on the right track or if there is a more standard way of doing hooks like these?

Currently the entire backend is written in C# but that is not a requirement.

[image]

Comment: Let's just use the term "plugin" to refer to user provided code. I'm curious about the nature of these plugins' capability. Since you've considered `eval` I suppose they're fine to run in client/browser env and don't require access to server env, is that correct?

Comment: If that's the case, then I'd say `eval` is not that "evil". The real risk of `eval` is mostly XSS attack. As long as you make sure your users can only run their own plugins, i.e. Bob's script doesn't end up running in Alice's browser, it's not risky. Of course, you should use [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) instead of `eval` to prevent private local scope leakage.

Comment: You’re half-right. I need to be able to run server-side code (I just assumed I could do that with eval as well). Though it would be a Big improvement if I could ALSO let users do client side code as well. I realize this will probably be two completely different solutions so for now the one that I need is server-side.

Comment: Bob’s code will in my case run in Alice’s browser as well. Though Bob is a system admin so maybe it is not as bad as you say. But yeah that is for the frontend :)

Comment: Speaking of security, allowing user to deploy onto server doesn't necessarily make it "safer" vs the `eval` approach. In fact, it gets even riskier, cus if you're not careful, mal-actor could just get control of your whole server.

Comment: I'm not really the guy to answer this question, I mostly work on frontend stuff. But still I'd share what I know. User deploying their code as "file on server" or "string in db" does really make much a diff. At the end they all ended up being parsed into bytes and loaded into memory. So start with "string in db" for it's simpler.

Comment: The real thing to watch is that, you're running untrusted user provided code on your infra. You'll want to make sure sandboxing is done properly. I don't have direct experience but I've once worked on a WebIDE project where we provide a bash shell for user work with on the cloud. The way we do it is to start a docker instance for that user on-the-fly, which's a VM with total control of all kind of access. So it's safe for him to do whatever he wants.

Comment: I’ve actually thought about that. So that the user provided code runs in a Docker instance (whether the code is stored in dB or provided by user as files). My “benefit” is that any user will run the same code. There is no user individual code so to speak. It will be an admin that makes scripts that is run for all users

Comment: OK, but can you treat the admin a "trusted" party?

Comment: @hackape In principal yes. Bur I suppose I should make it as safe as possible in case someone else gets access

Comment: I have some rough ideas, but I'm only familiar with Node.js on server-side. Will that still be helpful to you?

Comment: I actually was planning on using node.js so that would be suuuuuper appreciated! When I get home (1-hour ish) I can also specify a bit more about the setup for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just draft out the main framework, then wait for your feedback to fill in anything unclear.

> Disclaimer: I don't really have expertise with security and sandboxing. I just know it's an important thing, but really, it's beyond me. You go figure it out

Suppose we're now in a safe sandbox where all malicious behaviors are magically taken care, let's write some Node.js code for that "hook engine".

#### How users deploy their plugin code.

Let's assume we use file-base deployment. The interface you need to implement is a `PluginRegistry`.

```js
class PluginRegistry {
  constructor() {
    /**
    The plugin registry holds records of plugin info:

    type IPluginInfo = {
      userId: string,
      hash: string,
      filePath: string,
      module: null | object,
    }
    */

    this.records = new Map()
  }

  register(userId, info) {
    this.records.set(userId, info)
  }

  query(userId) {
    return this.records.get(userId)
  }
}

// plugin registry should be a singleton in your app.
const pluginRegistrySingleton = new PluginRegistry()

// app opens a http endpoint
// that accepts plugin registration
// this is how you receive user provided code
server.listen(port, (req, res) => {
  if (isPluginRegistration(req)) {
    let { userId, fileBytes, hash } = processRequest(req)
    let filePath = pluginDir + '/' + hash + '.js'

    let pluginInfo = {
      userId,
      // you should use some kind of hash
      // to uniquely identify plugin
      hash,
      filePath,
      // "module" field is left empty
      // it will be lazy-loaded when
      // plugin code is actually needed
      module: null,
    }

    let existingPluginInfo = pluginRegistrySingleton.query(userId)
    if (existingPluginInfo.hash === hash) {
      // already exist, skip
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      res.end('ok');
    } else {
      // plugin code written down somewhere
      fs.writeFile(filePath, fileBytes, (err) => {
        pluginRegistrySingleton.register(userId, pluginInfo)
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('ok');
      })
    }

  }
})
```

From the perspective of hook engine, it simply opens a HTTP endpoint to accept plugin registration, agnostic to the source.

Whether it's from CI/CD pipeline, or plain web interface upload, it doesn't matter. If you have CI/CD setup for your user, it is just a dedicated build machine that runs bash scripts isn't it? So just fire a `curl` call to this endpoint to upload whatever you need. Same applies to web interface.

#### How we would execute plugin code

User plugin code is just normal Node.js module code. You might instruct them to expose certain API and conform to your protocol.

```js
class HookEngine {
  constructor(pluginRegistry) {
    // dependency injection
    this.pluginRegistry = pluginRegistry
  }

  // hook
  oncreate(payload) {
    // hook call payload should identify the user
    const pluginInfo = this.pluginRegistry.query(payload.user.id)

    // lazy-load the plugin module when needed
    if (pluginInfo && !pluginInfo.module) {
      pluginInfo.module = require(pluginInfo.filePath)
    }

    // user plugin module is just normal Node.js module
    // you load it with `require`, and you call what ever function you need.
    pluginInfo.module.oncreate(payload)
  }
}
```

Comment: That is pretty cool.Øland very much in Line with what I need. Though as you say, it doesn’t really matter where the code comes from, so I guess I could even expose an editor myself i mu application and just save the content as a node module in the end? Or am I missing something in that case?

Comment: Yes you can. Source of the code doesn't matter. What matters is how you would execute the code safely, which is unfortunately not my expertise.

Comment: This lib [vm2](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2) came up when I searched about the topic. I don't know much about it, but from their readme it looks like something you might want to look into.

Comment: I guess there is no way to be truly safe. but I can ask others about that and how I avoid the most common issues. In any case thanks a lot for your help. It was really great to at least know that some solutions are at least possible!